# AngularJS Testing - Testing with $http and then() for AngularUI's typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with testing my function that I use with typeahead.js (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js). I usually know how to resolve a promise in tests, but not with the following function:

```
$scope.getSuggestion = function ( name, length ) {
  return $http.get( 'api/autocomplete/?contains=' + name )
    .then( function ( response ) {
      return response.data.slice( 0, length || 7 );
    });
};
```

My test looks like this:

```
describe('Suggestions', function () {
  it('should be possible to get suggestions', function () {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('api/autocomplete?title__contains=Foo').respond([
      { name: 'Foobar' },
      { name: 'Foobala' },
      { name: 'Foolooloo' }
    ]);
    var suggestions = $scope.getSuggestion( 'Foo' );
    $rootScope.$apply();

    // Here should be a test.
    console.log(suggestions);
  })
});
```

But `suggestion` only is the promise object `Object{then: function (callback, errback) { ... }}`.

Where did I mess up!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`suggestions` is a promise, it is **not** an actual value, you need to call `then()` to get the value out of it. That is

```
suggestions.then(function(data) {
    // Here should be a test.
    console.log(data);
});
```

***Update:***

Try this:

```
describe('Suggestions', function () {
  it('should be possible to get suggestions', function () {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('api/autocomplete?title__contains=Foo').respond([
      { name: 'Foobar' },
      { name: 'Foobala' },
      { name: 'Foolooloo' }
    ]);

    var suggestions;

    $scope.getSuggestion( 'Foo' ).then(function(data) {
        suggestions = data;
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();
    $rootScope.$apply(); // might be optional

    // Here should be a test.
    console.log(suggestions);
  })
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve here. Instead of getting the promise I want to get the resolved promise.

Comment: @distractedBySquirrels I don't think you have other ways to get the actual value of a promise except `then`, that's a bit unfortunate for now.

Comment: @distractedBySquirrels I updated my answer with a workaround.

Comment: @distractedBySquirrels The workaround has both `then()` and actual value `suggestions`, so you can easily test in both ways. Why do you think you can't test `then()`?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `$httpBackend` service, in order to 'force' it to respond to the request of the `$http` service, it is sufficient to cal `$httpBackEnd.flush();`. I believe the `$rootScope.$apply();` is redundant here.

Regarding the return value of the `$scope.getSuggestion` method, note that it will not return you the data from the server; it will return you a promise object which will be resolved once the request to the server is fulfilled.

Also note that promises can be chained, therefore the result of `$http(...).then(....)` in your method is still a promise.

Finally, the return statement in the callback passed as argument in `then` in your controller (`return response.data.slice( 0, length || 7 );`) will not be of much use; when the promise is resolved and this callback is invoked, you won't be able to get that return value.

You can of course provide code in the callback passed to `then` inside the controller method if there is something you need to do every time you call the `getSuggestion` method. If the 'client' of that method however needs the data the `$http` service returns, he will have to register his own callback to retrieve them.

So, to actually get the response data in your test (the 'client' of your controller method), you need to register the respective callbacks inside the test.

You can use the standard `then` method of the promise "interface" which expects you to pass two callbacks; the first will be called if the request succeeds (in your case if the $httpBackend is 'trained' to respond with a status in the 2XX range), the second one in case of an error. Alternatively you  could use the AngularJS specific `success` and `error` methods since the $http service returns an `HttpPromise`.

You can check out this approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/yianisn/rgk97/

See also [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) and [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

Comment: Not quite. I DO get that return value, b/c that is how promises work. You can see an working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eGG9Kj?p=preview
When the $http promise is resolved the `then` will fire and instead of returning a promise it will execute the function in the successful callback (I didn't specifie a cb for reject).

Comment: Ok, now I see your point.
Your example works because the typeahead directive "understands" promises (from their documentation: _Also this directive works with promises and it means that you can retrieve matches using the $http service with minimal effort._). 
In fact, this is the expected behavior in angular because the `$q` service itself is integrated with the Scope model observation mechanism (see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) - section _Differences between Kris Kowal's Q and $q_).
I guess the price you pay for this tight integration is that the code cannot be tested easily.